# Problem running Pydev

Tags: linux, eclipse, pydev

I am trying Django recently in Ububtu. So started using a developement environment, which is Pydev in Eclipse. I've installed all, but while configuring window>preferences>pydev>interpreter-python there are these problems I have:
What files in Linux should be selected?
Every time I select a file from /usr/lib/python2.6/disk-packages/pythonloader.py I get:
java.io.ioexception:permission denied.
I am running Eclipse under sudo.

Some help please
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `/usr/bin/python` or whatever path shows up from the command `which python`

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought the path is the one that I stated above. /usr/bin/python worked pretty well